# PHP get anonymous function key name

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I've got an array of anonymous functions like this. I need to get access to key of array inside this function like this:

```
$funcs = array(
   "fun_1" => function(){
         //want here to get fun_1 name (current array key)
         echo __KEY__; //echoes "fun_1"
    }
)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why not just pass the key to your anonymous function?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but this is an option:

```
    $funcs = array(
       "fun_1" => function($key){
              echo $key;
        }
    );

    foreach($funcs as $key => $func){
        $func($key);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Array elements hold references to data items. Hence different keys (or different elements of different arrays) may reference the same item. You can't determine which reference is being used inside the function - you need to store it as a parameter.

Consider:

```
$funcs = array(
   "fun_1" => function(){
     //want here to get fun_1 name (current array key)
     echo __KEY__; //echoes "fun_1"
   }
);
$funcs['fun_2']=$funcs['fun_1'];
```

What would you expect to happen when you call $funcs'fun_2'?